# No space left ec2 linux (AWS) shows /dev/xvda1 is 100% used

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M   81M  718M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       59G   58G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1000
```

it shows 100% used

I checked the root directory only 9.2 GB is used. not sure where is remaining 50 GB Consumed

```
sudo du -x  -d1 -h /
8.0K    /snap
4.0K    /mnt
4.0K    /lib64
4.0K    /srv
468K    /tmp
4.0K    /media
48K /root
14M /opt
450M    /var
218M    /lib
5.2G    /home
16M /bin
16K /lost+found
13M /sbin
6.0M    /etc
16K /~
85M /boot
1.3G    /usr
9.2G    /
```

Comment: @juzraai updated description

Answer (score 0):

The space is hold by linux process its can be cleared by greps/search the deleted process and kill those PIDS.

Command:

```
sudo lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'| awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill -9
```

After running above command it frees around 80% space:

**df -h**

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M   83M  716M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       59G  9.2G   48G  17% /
tmpfs           3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1000
```